# Single service account with multiple service providers and consumers of interfaces

Tags: windows, web-services, windows-services

How can I use a single service account for my stack with multiple service providers and consumers of interfaces on Windows (I still want traceability of changes)

Comment: Rathod, which web-services are you using? aws? It would be nice to know about which modules and services you are talking about (the commercial name of it).

Comment: @ Bruno, it's not aws, our services are windows based JSON over Rest API. Currently we authorize consumers of our services via service accounts. To minimize management of large number of service accounts, we want to use a single service account for entire stack (multiple applications and multiple interfaces). I am looking for a possible solution to implement this if feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Rathod, to use multiple services under the same service account, you must use a [Group Managed Service Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/service-accounts#bkmk-groupmanagedserviceaccounts). Therefore, the same rules will be applied to all your services.

Comment: @Bruno, probably I could have elaborated more to detail my scenario.

Comment: @Bruno, One of our enterprise suite has say 10 applications each expose 6-7 services [Rest APIs] to one another applications, it means remaining 9 applications can consume those services & capabilities vice versa. Currently we have one Service Account per application so we could trace in databases as in who made recent modifications/deletes based on the consumer Service Account. Due to some operational and management concerns there is a proposal to go with the same Service Account for all of the applications within the suite.

Comment: @Bruno, So now the question is, is there a way to achieve traceability of which application or who made modifications/delete since all the applications are under single Service Account

Comment: @RathodPankaj ok, got it.. I really don't know how to do this with service accounts, but why don't you trace API calls with a parameter added by each service at the API (a string or number that identifies each service, not related to the service account)? So, the same service account would solve the "logistics problem", and this parameter would solve traceability. Is that possible?

Comment: @Bruno, even that's what I initially thought but wanted to see if there are any other possible solutions from this community. I was thinking of adding a string in the header of API calls made without any change at the payload and parse that extra string from the header to pass into database. Is this the same you too suggest? Many Thanks!